# Labels loose value change of orientation with internationalization android

Tags: android, internationalization, orientation

I'm developing an Android app that uses Internationalization. 
So i have the folders values-language (e.g. values-en, values-br) in my solution. The internationalization is working well.

The problem is when i combine it with orientation elements.

I have also one xml file for landscape and other for portrait. I have the folders layout-orientation (e.g layout-port). The orientation is working well too. I accomplish this by overhiding the following method:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

But i'm having problems with the string values (labels). When i change the orientation, all the string values loose data and appers as ids. For example, I have a button that has a label "SAVE". When i rotate my phone, the label of the button changes to "@23232324" which is the number of the resource.

What can I do? I've tried to create portrait and landscape folders for each language that I have but didn't work (e.g values-br-port, values-br-land).

I need to keep both working, orientation and internationalization. I need to have two different layouts based on the orientation and also different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, I got it solved!!

The problem was that i was not calling the method setLocale before reloading the view.
So i had to do,

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setLocale();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

And the method setLocale:

```
public void setLocale(){
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```